# Blazor Slick Carousel

Tags: blazor, slick.js

I'm having this issue with Blazor Slick Carousel where the state change causes items to be rendered outside of the carousel. If I change states and come back to the same state more items get added to the carousel from the outside. If I click back and forth enough times most of the time all of the items make it back into the carousel.

Has anyone ever had this happen is there any known solutions? The bug seems random. It doesn't happen with every state change. Any help or leads would be appreciated.

The code behind:

```
namespace HorryCountySCGov.Web.Modules.HCCafe.FiscalBudgetUsage
{
 public partial class FiscalBudgetUsage : ComponentBase
 {
public string Division { get; set; } = null;
public string Department { get; set; } = null;
public string Category { get; set; } = null;
public List<DivisionModel> Divisions { get; set; } = new List<DivisionModel>();
public List<DepartmentModel> Departments { get; set; } = new List<DepartmentModel>();
public List<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; } = new List<CategoryModel>();
public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; } = new List<LineItem>();

public BlazorSlickCarousel Carousel { get; set; }
public WMBSCInitialSettings CarouselSettings { get; set; }
public WMBSCInitialSettings CarouselHalfCardSettings { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  CarouselSettings = new WMBSCInitialSettings
  {
    arrows = false,
    dots = false,
    slidesToShow = 3,
    slidesToScroll = 3,
    infinite = false ,
  };

  CarouselHalfCardSettings = new WMBSCInitialSettings
  {
    arrows = false,
    dots = false,
    slidesToShow = 3,
    slidesToScroll = 3,
    infinite = false, 

  };

  FiscalBudgetUsageRepository repo = new FiscalBudgetUsageRepository();
  Divisions = await repo.GetDivisions();
}


public async Task GoToDepartments(string division)
{
  Division = division;
  FiscalBudgetUsageRepository repo = new FiscalBudgetUsageRepository();
  Departments = await repo.GetDepartments(Division);
}

public async Task GoToCategories(string department, string division)
{

  Department = department;
  Division = division;
  FiscalBudgetUsageRepository repo = new FiscalBudgetUsageRepository();
  Categories = await repo.GetCategories(Department, Division);
}

public async Task GoToLineItems(string category, string department, string division)
{
  Category = category;
  Department = department;
  Division = division;
  FiscalBudgetUsageRepository repo = new 
FiscalBudgetUsageRepository();
  LineItems = await repo.GetLineItems(Category, Department, Division);
}

public async Task ChangeDivision(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
  Division = (string)args.Value;
  Department = null;
  Category = null;
  await GoToDepartments(Division);
}

public async Task ChangeDepartment(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
  Department = (string)args.Value;
  Category = null;
  await GoToCategories(Department, Division);
}

public async Task ChangeCategory(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
  Category = (string)args.Value;
  await GoToLineItems(Category, Department, Division);
}

public async Task Reset()
{
  Category = null;
  Department = null;
  Division = null;
  await OnInitializedAsync();
}


public double GetYTDPercent()
{
  int budgetYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
  if (DateTime.Now.Month >= 7) { budgetYear++; }
  TimeSpan sinceJuly1st = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(budgetYear - 1, 7, 1));
  return (sinceJuly1st.Days / 365.0) * 100.0;
}

private string ShortenCurrency(decimal number)
{
  if (number >= 10000000) { return (number / 1000000).ToString("#,0M"); }
  if (number >= 1000000) { return (number / 1000000).ToString("0.#") + "M"; }
  if (number >= 100000) { return (number / 1000).ToString("#,0K"); }
  if (number >= 10000) { return (number / 1000).ToString("0.#") + "K"; }
  return number.ToString("#,0");
}
  }
}
```

The razor component:

```
<div class="fbu-dashboard government light">
@if (Division == null)
{
    <div class="item toolkit">
        <h2 style="margin-bottom: .25rem;">
            Fiscal Budget
            <span class="sub-title">Pacing Status</span>
        </h2>
        @if (Division == null)
        {
            string color = "business";
            decimal CountyBudget = 0;
            decimal CountyActual = 0;

            foreach (var part in Divisions)
            {
                CountyActual += part.Actual;
                CountyBudget += part.Budget;
            }

            var ytdPercent = (decimal)GetYTDPercent();
            var available = CountyBudget - CountyActual;
            var pacingLimit = (CountyBudget * (ytdPercent) / 100) - CountyActual;
            var percentUsed = CountyActual / (CountyBudget == 0 ? 1 : CountyBudget) * 100;

            if (CountyActual > CountyBudget)
            {
                color = "resident";
            }
            else if (percentUsed > ytdPercent)
            {
                color = "visitor";

            }

            <div class="item half-card @color" style="width: calc(100% - 1rem);">
                <span class="label">County</span>
                <figure class="horizontal-bar side-by-side" style="--percentComplete: @GetYTDPercent().ToString()%">
                    <section class="horizontal-line">
                        <div class="graph-line @color">
                            <span class="issued" style="width:@(percentUsed <= 100 ? $"{percentUsed}%" : "100%" )"></span>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </figure>
                <div class="overview">
                    <div class="quick-info">
                        <span class="label">Year to Date</span>
                        <span class="numbers">$@ShortenCurrency(CountyActual)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quick-info">
                        <span class="label">Budget</span>
                        <span class="numbers">$@ShortenCurrency(CountyBudget)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        }

    </div>

     @foreach (var divisionChunk in Divisions.Chunk(2))
    {
      <div class="blazor-item">
        @foreach (var divisionItem in divisionChunk)
        {
          <HalfCard Model="divisionItem" OnGoto="(string division) => GoToDepartments(division)"/>
        }
      </div>
    }
} else if (Department == null){
     <BlazorSlickCarousel @ref="Carousel" Configurations="CarouselHalfCardSettings">
       <BlazorSlickCarouselContent>
         <div class="item toolkit">
          <h2 style="margin-bottom: .25rem;">
              Fiscal Budget
              <span class="sub-title">Pacing Status</span>
          </h2>
          <label>Division</label>
            <select value="@Division" @onchange="ChangeDivision">
                @foreach (var option1 in Divisions)
                {
                    <option value="@option1.Name">@option1.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
          <div class="back" @onclick="Reset" style="position:absolute; bottom: 1rem;">
              <span class="img-container"><img src="/images/right-arrow-icon.svg"></span>Back
          </div>
         </div>
          @foreach (var departmentChunk in Departments.Chunk(2))
          {
            <div class="blazor-item">
              @foreach (var deptItem in departmentChunk)
              {
                <HalfCard Model="deptItem" OnGoto="(string dept) => GoToCategories(dept, Division)" />
              }
            </div>
              }
       </BlazorSlickCarouselContent>
    </BlazorSlickCarousel>
} else if (Category == null)
{

    <BlazorSlickCarousel @ref="Carousel" Configurations="CarouselHalfCardSettings">
       <BlazorSlickCarouselContent>
         <div class="item toolkit">
          <h2 style="margin-bottom: .25rem;">
              Fiscal Budget
              <span class="sub-title">Pacing Status</span>
          </h2>
          <label>Division</label>
            <select value="@Division" @onchange="ChangeDivision">
                @foreach (var option1 in Divisions)
                {
                    <option value="@option1.Name">@option1.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
              <label>Department</label>
              <select value="@Department" @onchange="ChangeDepartment">
                  @foreach (var option2 in Departments)
                  {
                      <option value="@option2.Name">@option2.Name</option>
                  }
              </select>
          <div class="back" @onclick="Reset" style="position:absolute; bottom: 1rem;">
              <span class="img-container"><img src="/images/right-arrow-icon.svg"></span>Back
          </div>
         </div>
          @foreach (var categoryChunk in Categories.Chunk(2))
              { 
                <div class="blazor-item">
                  @foreach (var catItem in categoryChunk)
                  {
                    <HalfCard Model="catItem" OnGoto="(string category) => GoToLineItems(category, Department, Division)" />
                  }
                </div>
              }
       </BlazorSlickCarouselContent>
    </BlazorSlickCarousel>
} else
{
   <BlazorSlickCarousel @ref="Carousel" Configurations="CarouselHalfCardSettings">
       <BlazorSlickCarouselContent>
         <div class="item toolkit">
          <h2 style="margin-bottom: .25rem;">
              Fiscal Budget
              <span class="sub-title">Pacing Status</span>
          </h2>
          <label>Division</label>
            <select value="@Division" @onchange="ChangeDivision">
                @foreach (var option1 in Divisions)
                {
                    <option value="@option1.Name">@option1.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
              <label>Department</label>
              <select value="@Department" @onchange="ChangeDepartment">
                  @foreach (var option2 in Departments)
                  {
                      <option value="@option2.Name">@option2.Name</option>
                  }
              </select>
               <label>Category</label>
              <select value="@Category" @onchange="ChangeCategory">
                  @foreach (var option3 in Categories)
                  {
                      <option value="@option3.Name">@option3.Name</option>
                  }
              </select>
          <div class="back" @onclick="Reset" style="position:absolute; bottom: 1rem;">
              <span class="img-container"><img src="/images/right-arrow-icon.svg"></span>Back
          </div>
         </div>
            @foreach (var lineItem in LineItems)
              {
                  <LineItemCard Item="lineItem" />
              }
       </BlazorSlickCarouselContent>
    </BlazorSlickCarousel> 
}
```

[image]

I already had it wrapped only once around the outside. Wrapping each one made it better but didn't resolve the problem. The carousel is getting rendered then the information that's supposed to go in it.

Comment: Please add your code generating the carousel.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine It's a bit beefy, but I hope that helps

Comment: When you say "state change", do you mean when you select a category, department or division? I don't know much about this `BlazorSlickCarousel`, so I don't really know how it acts. Maybe it does not like being fully rerendered. From what I saw, you have some duplicated code in the last 3 `else`, you could define `BlazorSlickCarousel` only once.

Comment: Yes to all.  `BlazorSlickCarousel` doesn't seem to like a partial rerender either. Yes I have the duplicated code.  My original was one carousel and my toolkit contained all of the if conditions for drawing the new selects.

What is mind boggling is that it worked perfectly for weeks and I can't figure out what's caused it behave differently

Comment: I suggest you try to reduce your issue, try creating another page with a very simple `BlazorSlickCarousel`, see if it works as expected. Then make it come closer to what you actually have by steps to detect where is your issue coming from.